# Fibonacci sequence for the determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

It's really easy question but I think I'm missing some points.

Let $F_n$ is $n$ by $n$ matrix  $$F_n=\det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & & & & \\ 1 & 1 & -1 & & & \\ & 1 & 1 & -1 & & \\ & & . & . & . \\ & & & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then $F_n=a_{11}c_{11}+a_{12}c_{12}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$
where $a_{ij}$ is $(i,j)$ element of the matrix and $c_{ij}$ is cofactor.

I can't understand the second entry $F_{n-2}$. I think $a_{12}c_{12}$ is not $F_{n-2}$ since it doesn't have $1$ in $(2,1)$ entry of the matrix.

Comment: who are $a_{ij}$ and $c_{ij}$? which is the size of the matrix you are evaluating the determinant of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at a simple example and you will see the pattern. Perform Laplace expansion of $F_4$ along the first row, we get
$$F_4
=\left\lvert\begin{matrix}1&-1\\1&1&-1\\&1&1&-1\\&&1&1\end{matrix}\right\rvert
=F_3 + \underbrace{(-1)}_{a_{12}} \times 
\underbrace{(-1)\left\lvert\begin{matrix}1&-1\\&1&-1\\&1&1\end{matrix}\right\rvert}_{c_{12}}.
$$
Now, expand the second 3x3 minor on RHS along the first column, we get
$$
\left\lvert\begin{matrix}1&-1\\&1&-1\\&1&1\end{matrix}\right\rvert
=\left\lvert\begin{matrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{matrix}\right\rvert
=F_2.
$$
Hence $F_4=F_3+F_2$.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I think I should've calculated directly as you did. Thanks!